What do I use to replace FlutterView window when customizing RenderView class in the new versions of Flutter(like 3.1 and beyond)?
I updated from Dart 3.0 to 3.2 and I am getting some execution errors.
Original code using window that worked up to 3.0.5:
Before
Tried to change to use View class to work with 3.19.0 and over:
After
I am getting:
Unhandled Exception: type '_ReusableRenderView' is not a subtype of type '_ExposedRenderView' in type
cast
The following asserting was thrown:
The render object for SizedBox cannot find ancestor render object to attach to.
The ownership chain for the RenderObject in question was:
SizedBox ← [root]
Try wrapping your widget in a View widget or any other widget that is backed by a RenderTreeRootElement to serve as the root of the render tree.
My problem is very close to:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/141009
Resume: I need to replace window component to create a RenderView, but it looks like View works fine when you have a Tree/Widget component binding to your mobile root tree app, when I am using a Windows one.
